# store mod_login password in joomla session

Tags: php, joomla

We are using Joomla for the company's portal and a separate interface written in java as something like a data warehouse.

Now there are some integration problems. The encryption method of joomla portal is different from the data warehouse and we need the users logged in portal to be able to log in to data warehouse interface without providing login information again.

I need to store the plain joomla password in session and then retrieve and encode with the encryption method of data warehouse interface.

Now my question is: in which file  mod_login authenticates and the plain password is still alive so that i can store the plain password(or encrypted password using data warehouse's method) in session to retrieve it later?

I'm a Joomla newbie ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't mod_login who makes the real authentication, you should look at components/com_user (in your case, you should probably look at the controller). Anyway, try not to modify any Joomla core files, may be you can achieve the same result by creating a plugin (if I'm not wrong, there's an event called something like "onUserLogin").

I hope it helped!

After some research, I think the event you should use is "onUserAuthenticate". You can see how to use it in /plugins/authentication/joomla.

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) I edited /plugin/authentication/joomla.php and added plain password to JSession. Great :)

Comment: You should be careful with those changes as they can potentially be overwritten any time you update Joomla.

Comment: Yes, there are alternatives. What you should do is create your own plugin, implementing the "onUserAuthenticate" method, or whatever method you need (see the name of the method you modified). That way you would keep your code even after updating Joomla.